# createRecordEvent failing in Lightning Component after Winter '16 update. Anyone else having the issue?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

We have a Lightning Component that has a button to create new Event or Tasks. Everything was working, until Winter '16 update. Now when you click on this button, we get the following error:

**ERROR**
Create null
Looks like there's a problem.
You don't have access to this record. Ask your administrator for help or to request access.

*The code that is executing is as follows:*

var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName":  "event"
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();

Any idea what's got changed in winter '16?

Comment: JavaScript buttons are no longer supported in LEX.  Could that be the issue?
--Page 59 of Winter '16 Release Notes:  Custom buttons that use a URL or JavaScript content source aren’t supported in Lightning Experience. You can replace some of the
functions covered by these buttons by using point-and-click tools like Process Builder, Visual Workflow, or code-driven approaches."

Comment: We are not using javascript button, the code for button is:  <br/> <ui:button label="New" class="right" press="{!c.newEvent}"/>

Comment: **The code for newEvent function is as follows**  ' newEvent : function(component, event,helper) {
        
        var createRecordEvent = $A.get("e.force:createRecord");
        createRecordEvent.setParams({
            "entityApiName":  "event"
        });
        createRecordEvent.fire();
    }'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specify the entityApiName as "event", when it should be "Event".  Perhaps this case sensitivity was only enforced in Winter 16.

Comment: Awesome! It looks like that was the issue. It seems they enforced case sensitivity now. I assume with API name it should be. Thanks again